# Collections.synchronizedMap(Map) after migration to Linux - second Thread doesn't see new entry

Tags: java, linux, windows, concurrency, synchronization

I have the following issue after trying to run my webapplication on Linux server.

When running on windows, everything works perfectly (simplified version) - call send() method, wait for JMS response on synchronizer object, send the response to client)...

When started on linux server (same JVM version - 1.7, bytecode - java 1.5 version), I get response only for the first message, and following error in log for the rest of the messages:

```
synchronizer is null /*my_generated_message_id*/
```

It looks like JMS message listener thread cannot see new entries (created in JMS sender Thread) in synchronizers map, but I don't understand why...

Synchronizers Map definition:

```
public final Map<String, ReqRespSynchro<Map>> synchronizers 
    = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, ReqRespSynchro<Map>>());
```

Sending JMS request with active response awaiting:

```
@Override
public Map send(Map<String,Object> params) {
    String msgIdent  = ""/*my_generated_message_id*/;
    Map response = null;

    ReqRespSynchro<Map> synchronizer = synchronizers.get(msgIdent);
    if (synchronizer == null) {
        synchronizer = new ReqRespSynchro<Map>();
        synchronizers.put(msgIdent , synchronizer);
    }

    synchronized(synchronizer) {
        try {
                sender.send(params);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("send error", ex);
        }

        synchronizer.initSendSequence();
        int iter = 1;
        try {
            while (!synchronizer.isSet() && iter > 0) {
                synchronizer.wait(this.waitTimeout);
                iter--;
            }    
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("send error 2", ex);
            return null;
        } finally {
            response = (synchronizers.remove(msgIdent )).getRespObject();
        }           
    }
    return response;
}
```

JMS onMessage response processing (separate thread):

```
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        Map<String,Object> response = (Map<String,Object>) om.getObject();
        String msgIdent = response.getMyMsgID(); ///*my_generated_message_id*/

        ReqRespSynchro<Map> synchronizer = synchronizers.get(msgIdent);
        if (synchronizer != null) {
            synchronized (synchronizer) {
                msgSynchronizer.setRespObject(response);
                synchronizer.notify();
            }
        } else {
            log.error("synchronizer is null " + msgIdent);
        }
}
```

Synchronizer class:

```
public class ReqRespSynchro<E> {
    private E obj = null;

    public synchronized void setRespObject(E obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public synchronized void initSendSequence() {
        this.obj = null;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isSet() {
        return this.obj != null;
    }

    public synchronized E getRespObject() {
        E ret = null;
        ret = obj;              
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not using `ConcurrentHashMap` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Your code bears the “check-then-act” anti-pattern.

```
ReqRespSynchro<Map> synchronizer = synchronizers.get(msgIdent);
if (synchronizer == null) {
    synchronizer = new ReqRespSynchro<Map>();
    synchronizers.put(msgIdent , synchronizer);
}
```

Here, you first *check* whether the `synchronizers` contains a particular mapping then you *act* by putting a new mapping when the mapping is not present, but by the time you act, there is no guaranty that the condition you have checked still holds.

While the map returned by `Collections.synchronizedMap` guarantees thread-safe `put` and `get` methods, it does not (and can’t) guaranty that there won’t be an update between subsequent invocation of `get` and `put`.

So if two threads execute the code above, there is the possibility that one thread puts a new value while the other already has performed the `get` operation but not the `put` operation and will therefore proceed with putting a new value, overwriting the existing. So the threads will use different `ReqRespSynchro` instances and so will the other threads get either of these from the map.

The correct use would be to synchronize the entire compound operation:

```
synchronized(synchronizers) {
    ReqRespSynchro<Map> synchronizer = synchronizers.get(msgIdent);
    if (synchronizer == null) {
        synchronizer = new ReqRespSynchro<Map>();
        synchronizers.put(msgIdent , synchronizer);
    }
}
```

It’s a common mistake to think that by wrapping a map or collection into a synchronized one, every thread safety issue was solved. But you still have to think about access patterns and guard compound operations manually, so sometimes you’re better off using manual locking only and resist the temptation of easy-to-use synchronized wrappers.

---

But note the [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) was added to the Java API to address this use pattern (amongst others).

Change the map declaration to

```
public final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ReqRespSynchro<Map>> synchronizers
    = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

This map provides thread safe `put` and `get` methods, but also methods allowing to avoid the “check-then-act” anti-pattern for updates.

Using the `ConcurrentMap` under Java 8 is especially easy:

```
ReqRespSynchro<Map> synchronizer = synchronizers
    .computeIfAbsent(msgIdent, key -> new ReqRespSynchro<>());
```

The invocation of [`computeIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) will get the `ReqRespSynchro<Map>`, if there is one, otherwise the provided function will be executed to compute a value which will get stored, all with *atomicity* guaranty. The places where you simply `get` an existing instance need no change.

The pre-Java 8 code is a bit more convoluted:

```
ReqRespSynchro<Map> synchronizer = synchronizers.get(msgIdent);
if (synchronizer == null) {
    synchronizer = new ReqRespSynchro<>();
    ReqRespSynchro<Map> concurrent = synchronizers.putIfAbsent(msgIdent , synchronizer);
    if(concurrent!=null) synchronizer = concurrent;
}
```

Here, we can’t perform the operation atomically, but we are able to detect if a concurrent update happened in-between. In this case, [`putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) will not modify the map but return the value already contained in the map. So if we encounter such a situation, all we have to do is to use that existing one instead of the one we attempted to put.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your waitTimeout in send() method is too short. You only have one iteration set for the waiting cycle. So the msgIdent entry may be removed from the map in finally block in send before it can be read in onMessage(): wait timeout expires, iteration counter is decremented, thread exits the cycle and removes the entry from map.

Even if waitTimeout is long enough you may experience a so-called spurious wakeup:

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied.

By the way why don't you send response back via JMS without some cryptic synchronization? Here is an example for ActiveMQ message broker: [How should I implement request response with JMS?](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html)